# multiple Facebook Elements, multiple loading of resources

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, sdk

If you use more than one Facebook-Element (f.e. like button) on your page with the Facebook SDK, some JS-Scripts from Facebook are loaded multiple times. If you browse uncached on mobile it`s annoying.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.4'
            });
        };
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async=true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Facebook Social Widget Testpage</h1>

    <h2>Like Buttons</h2>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="//facebook.com/intouchmagazin/1" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div><br><br>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="//facebook.com/intouchmagazin/2" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div><br><br>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="//facebook.com/intouchmagazin/3" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div><br><br>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="//facebook.com/intouchmagazin/4" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

    <h2>Posts</h2>
    <div class="fb-post" data-href="//www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151471074398553" data-width="500"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run this code and check your network-monitor, you`ll see, that a  300KB Js from Facebook is loaded 4(!) times.

Any ideas to prevent this?

Comment: Check if the content of the JS is actually the same. I bet it is not.